# Can Excel Conditional Formatting use UDFs in the condition?

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I have a cell in Excel that I want to format differently based on a user defined formula (UDF) - my formula tests whether there is a formula in the cell...

I am trying to use conditional formatting with my UDF to format the cell - but it does not seem to be working.

My condition is this:

```
="isManualPrice(R22C12)"
```

I tried without the quotes, but get the error

> You cannot use references to other
>   worksheets or workbooks for
>   Conditional Formatting criteria

Perhaps the issue relates to my UDF being defined in a separate macro workbook and not my main workbook...

I see its mentioned in this [blog entry from 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2005/10/13/480599.aspx), but only in passing...

Thanks in advance.
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Your problem is simply that you've got quotes in there. You need to choose "Formula Is" from the drop-down, and then your formula should be

```
=isManualPrice(R22C12)
```

...with no quotes.

(I'm more used to A1 notation rather than R1C1 notation but I assume that'll work just as well).

Comment: mmm - I tried that, but I get an error , see edit to original question

Comment: got it working - the problem is that the UDF needs to be in the same workbook, doh.

Comment: It will also work if the UDF is in a module.  This is how I am using it.