# Excel VBA - User Defined Function in Condictional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I built a User Defined Function with VBA code and it works fine in Excel if I use it in a formula to populate cell values.  However, I cannot use this function in conditional formatting.  I'm getting message "This type of reference cannot be used in a Conditional Formatting formula".

I'm curious if any UDF can be used in conditional formatting?  Or no UDF is allowed at all?  Thanks!

[image]

[image]

UDF Codes is as below:

```
Function isValidMAC(mac As String) As Boolean

Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String

' Exact 12 characters.  Valid characters are a-f or A-F or 0-9
strPattern = "^[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$"

With regex
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = False
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

isValidMAC = regex.Test(mac)

End Function
```

Comment: Did you put the code in a public module or private worksheet code sheet?

Comment: Which code were you referring to?  For the UDF code, it's in public module, otherwise it won't be visible to Excel users at all.  The interesting thing is - Excel allows bogus function name in conditional formatting formula (.e.g "=XXX($A$1)").  However Excel complains about a valid UDF.

Comment: Very similar to this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207001/can-excel-conditional-formatting-use-udfs-in-the-condition?rq=1).  My UDF is in a module.  The function is declared as public function.  But I don't know how to declared the module as public (if there's such as thing called "public module").  :)

Comment: module code sheets are public by default; worksheet code sheets are private by nature.

Comment: The UDF just needs to be in a **Regular** Module in the **Same** workbook.  And your formula shoud return `True` or `False`

Comment: My UDF works fine as shown in the first screenshot.  It's just that the conditional formatting won't accept this UDF (as shown in 2nd screenshot).  How weird!

Comment: Not weird at all. The problem is in how you coded the udf.

Comment: Added the UDF code in original post.  Can you please take a look and see if there's any potential issue with it?  Thank you very much!

Comment: It works fine for me so the answer is yes you can use an UDF and you can use this one. At least with Excel 2016.

Comment: Where is the code located?  Same workbook?  Regular module?

Comment: The UDF code is located in a regular module.  The module is in a .xlam file loaded as Add-in.  What I don't understand was - why I can reference the UDF in a cell formula but cannot reference it in a conditional formatting?  What's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your UDF is not is the same workbook, but in your add-in, you will receive this message;
As a workaround: use your UDF-call in a defined name and use this Defined Name in your conditional Formatting Formula

Comment: thank you very much for your info.  How do I use the UDF-call in a defined name?  Thanks again!

Comment: select your MAC-numbers in column D, insert 'dnIsValidMac' as a Name, in the Box Refers to: =ISVALIDMAC($D2). Now go to conditional formatting and type the formula: =dnIsValidMac

Comment: Is there a way to do this in VBA code?  Thanks again!

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="dnIsValidMac", RefersTo:="=IsValidMac($D2)"

Comment: Sorry for being dumb.  But is there anyway I can define a name so that it can work like a function?  i.e. is there a way to define a name 'dnIsValidMac()'.  Then I can use 'dnIsValidMac' like a built-in function and put in the cell name as the parameter?  i.e. =dnIsValidMac(A1), =dnIsValidMac(B2), etc.?

Comment: No, because the () are not allowed in a (name of a ) defined name